# Has anyone made the Video.js player 508 Accessible

Tags: flash, accessibility, video.js, section508

I'm using video.js in a project that must be 508 accessible, editing the js and the css for this was relatively simple, but the people doing the 508 testing are using an older version of IE to test it, and the Flash Fallback is not passing the 508 tests.

I'm curious if anyone has; 
A) already solved this issue?
B) Can provide me with to the FLA and any SRC codes to video.js video player so that I can make the edits.
C) Or of course, suggest anything that will solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: How old of a version of IE?  C) Use a more accessible browser and stop wasting your time???

Comment: I have no control over the browser they are using, I simply have to accept it and work with it.  And IE7.  I was dumbfounded.

Comment: To be completely honest, you're wasting your time.  Anything that is accessible in IE7 is going to be completely broken for every other browser/AT combination out there.  You're going to have to do some browser sniffing to even get close, and nobody else will have wasted their time on that!  Unless you're just going for basic keyboard/visual accessibility, but if you were doing that, you probably wouldn't be asking this question.  I have a violin over here that is playing a sad song for you...

Comment: I just need to make the Flash Fallback, that it is already using, accessible.  This should work for any browser that calls it up (with flash).  I'm thinking it's a half hour fix with the source code.

Comment: What is the fall back currently?

Comment: The fall back is currently their default SWF that downloads with it.

Comment: Wait what? Your fallback is their (agency) own stuff, and they say that _that_ isn't compliant? If I read that correctly, that's something they need to clean up, unless you are doing something unique to it. What are they saying in regards how it fails?

Comment: Sorry, miscomunication on my part.  The Video.js [ http://www.videojs.com/ ] has a custom Flash SWF that it fallsback on if the browser does not recognize the video tag (among other reasons).  I am currently using the one that comes with a download of video.js.  But it is compiled and I can not go in and edit it.  I guess I'm looking for a new SWF that has some additional consideration taken with accessibility (either pre-built or the original FLA file that I can edit).

Comment: Thanks for that. If you cannot get an answer, could you possibly use JWPlayer? That meets requirements.

Comment: JWPlayer looks to do everything that I need.  The only issue is the pricing structure... the client is not ok with other branding/watermarks, so the free version is not an option.  Then these are being used to build SCORM modules that will be placed on to different sites (I don't know of in advance), so the "up-to-10-sites" looks prohibitive as well.  

But it works the way I want video.js to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the most recent version of videojs 4.1.0? I've tested this and it works.

The fallback won't work if you're running it locally however. Always make sure it's running off a server.

Comment: While it technically works, or is keyboard accessible, it does not provide any visual cues to show the user what control is currently in focus.  So, although I have the play button in focus, and hitting "SPACE" will allow me to toggle the play/pause, I need to have a highlight or bounding box around the control so it's obvious that it is selected.

Comment: You can deal with that still using css. You can use the outline property. <style>
div 
{
outline:green dotted thick;
}
</style>

Comment: I recommend yellow vs green since that is the usual visual indicator for flash. Are you testing this with JAWS/NVDA/etc?

Comment: You are absolutely right, setting the Outline property does and did transfer back to the Flash version!  Thank you, I knew that the FlashFallback made a stab at using the CSS, but I did not expect that to work.